# $\Vert x\Vert$ in terms of bounded linear functional $f$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, $X'$ be its dual and $f \in X'$. Then we have $$\Vert x\Vert=\sup_{f \neq0}{|f(x)| \over \Vert f\Vert}$$
Then, is the following also true $$\Vert x\Vert=\sup_{\Vert f\Vert=1} |f(x)|$$?

Comment: [Using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5C%7Cx%5C%7C%3D%5Csup_%7B%5C%7Cf%5C%7C%3D1%7D%20%7Cf(x)%7C%24&p=1) I was able to find this: [The norm of $x\in X$, where $X$ is a normed linear space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77239) and [The norm of a bounded linear operator has this formula: $\|T\| = \sup_{\|v\| = 1} \|T v\|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1412108).

Answer (score 0):

Let's rename $x$ to $x_0$. For $x_0 = 0$, the claim is easily derived using linearity. For $x_0 \neq 0$ one can apply a corollary of Hahn-Banach ensuring the existence of a functional $x_0' \in X'$ with $x_0'(x_0) = \Vert x_0 \Vert$ and $\Vert x_0' \Vert = 1$. Therefore we have

$$\Vert x_0 \Vert \le \sup_{\Vert f \Vert = 1} |f(x_0)|$$

Since $f \in X'$, we also have $\sup_{\Vert f \Vert = 1} |f(x_0)| \le \sup_{\Vert f \Vert = 1} \Vert f \Vert \Vert x_0 \Vert = \Vert x_0\Vert$. Combining both results yields the claim.